# Is there a way to bypass overflow:hidden so an absolute positioned div could appear outside of it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, animation

I have a menu, and on each `<li>` there's a class making it `overflow: hidden;` so I can achieve an animation on it. The thing is on one of these list-item's there's a sub-menu. This sub-menu is `position: absolute;`. The overflow is making it so you can't see it when it's being clicked on. If I remove `overflow: hidden;` the animation breaks. I'm not sure what to do. Unless there's a way to bypass, I'm thinking for my sub-menu to appear I'd have to scrap the animation entirely.

**Animation**

```
/* Wayra */
.wayra {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    transition: border-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
}
/*.wayra.contact-item {
    overflow: visible;
}*/
.wayra::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #281879;
    /*z-index: -1;*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg) translate3d(0, -3em, 0);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg) translate3d(0, -3em, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
}
.wayra a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.wayra a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.wayra:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #281879;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
}
```

**Dropdown**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

Here's a link to a [demo](http://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/rawafid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding that effect to `a` instead of `li`? Let's translate:

- `.wyara` should get overflow:visible,
- `.wyara > a` should get overflow:hidden,
- `.wayra::before` becomes `.wayra > a::before`,
- `.wayra:hover::before` becomes `.wyara:hover > a::before, .wayra.open > a::before`

Just tried it with Stylish, looks good.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Any ideas on how to get it to cover the `border-right` it has too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override it when hovering over the element:

```
.wayra:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I strongly believe that is not possible. But there have to be other methods to do something like this. If you want to have an animation, you will have to rewrite your menu from scratch.